# Fourier series: Show that $\sum_{n\ne 0} \bigl| \hat{f}(n) \bigr|^2 \le 1/(4\pi^2)$

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-series

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ which is $1$-periodic and $f\in C^1$. Also, $\int_0^1 \left| f' \right| \le 1$. Show that $\sum_{n\ne 0} \left| \hat{f}(n) \right|^2 \le \frac{1}{4\pi^2}$.
>
> (*) $\hat{f}(n)$ is the $n$-th Fourier coefficient.

First, I'm familiar with Bessel's inequality that $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \left| \hat{f}(n) \right|^2 \le \| f \| = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\left| f \right|^2$

We know that:

$$\left| \int_0^1 f'  \right| = \left|f(1)-f(0)\right| \le \int_0^1 f' \le 1$$

But that's something we already knew because $f$ is $1$-periodic so $f(1)-f(0) = 0$.

So I'm not sure how utilize this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$ f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(n)e^{2\pi inx},x\in[0,1] $$
where
$$\hat{f}(n)=\int_0^{1} f(x)e^{-2\pi inx}dx. $$
Since
$$ \hat{f}'(n)=\int_0^{1} f'(x)e^{-2\pi inx}dx=2\pi i n\hat{f}(n), $$
by Parsevel's Identity
$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |\hat{f}(n)|^2=\int_0^{1}|f(x)|^2dx, $$
we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n\neq 0} |\hat{f}(n)|^2&=&\sum_{n\neq 0}\frac{1}{4\pi^2n^2}|\hat{f}'(n)|^2\\
&\le&\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\sum_{n\neq 0}|\hat{f}'(n)|^2\\
&\le&\frac{1}{4\pi^2}
\end{eqnarray}